# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.querySelector('.alert > .bar.passed').innerText')

Tags: continuous-integration, jasmine, phantomjs, teamcity-8.0

For some reason I'm getting intermittent failure to run (or at least report the running of) my jasmine tests. the error lies in run-jasmine.js and the error manifests itself as

```
`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.querySelector('.alert > .bar.passed').innerText')
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():58
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():61`
```

I am running TeamCity 8.1.3 (build 30101), Jasmine 2.2.0 and phantomjs 2.0.0.
Build step command parameters are

```
--web-security=no
--local-to-remote-url-access=yes
--ignore-ssl-errors=yes
jasmine/run-jasmine.js
specs/SpecsRunner.html
```

I've tried downgrading Jasmine and phantomjs but no change. I've also tried various run-jasmine.js scripts but to no avail. Is anyone else having a similar problem?

Everything was fine until a few days ago and now it happens 90% of the time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somebody probably changed the site and now you have to adjust the tests to the new requirements or hit the person on the head.

Comment: I wish. All the tests run fine in a browser. The TypeError is occurring in run-jasmine.js script.

Comment: Did you recently update any of the tools you mentioned? You possibly need to wait a little before something. The error suggests that the element is not yet present on the page. Maybe you're asserting it too fast.

Comment: I have the same problem, and have also tried various run-jasmine.js scripts. Haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: Cheers Jim, at least now I don't feel alone. Will post back here if I find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a new run-jasmine.js script that does the job.

[daniel-chambers / run-jasmine.js](https://gist.github.com/daniel-chambers/f783d8ef869e64281e98/937d16ba9284cfadb5a7fecd0f08d9f1946a68a0)

I tried this script before but was getting a problem with timeouts so I moved on but now I've increased the 'Default Max Timeout' in the script to 60 seconds, it seems to do the trick just fine.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the problem.